# Django Runtime error

Tags: python, django, tinymce

I'm creating a django application and I recently installed django tinymce. I added the app to my settings.py. But when I try to migrate, I get this error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7fec01852d70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda2/envs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda2/envs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda2/envs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 374, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda2/envs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda2/envs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda2/envs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda2/envs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda2/envs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda2/envs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 313, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda2/envs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda2/envs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 306, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda2/envs/my_env/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/agozie/kingdom-ambassadors/kingdom/urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    url(r'^', include('blog.urls')),
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda2/envs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda2/envs/my_env/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/agozie/kingdom-ambassadors/blog/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from blog import views
  File "/home/agozie/kingdom-ambassadors/blog/views.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .forms import RegisterForm, LoginForm, CommentForm
  File "/home/agozie/kingdom-ambassadors/blog/forms.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda2/envs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/flatpages/models.py", line 11, in <module>
    class FlatPage(models.Model):
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda2/envs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 113, in __new__
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.flatpages.models.FlatPage doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

Here is my settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'blog',
    'tinymce',
]

SITE_ID = 1
```

How do I solve this problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As instructed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/flatpages/#installation), you must

> Add `'django.contrib.flatpages'` to your [`INSTALLED_APPS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-INSTALLED_APPS) setting.

Also make sure you're either using `FlatpageFallbackMiddleware` or you've got your URLs configured properly (see the previous link).